# how to solve magento2 reindexer issue

Tags: magento2, reindex

when we delete products from magento backhand after while reindexing its showing duplicate entry error like below:

```
SELECT `cpe`.`entity_id`, `pdd`.`attribute_id`, `cs`.`store_id`, IF(pds.value_id > 0, pds.value, pdd.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS pdd CROSS JOIN `store` AS `cs`
```

LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `pds` ON pds.entity_id = pdd.entity_id AND pds.attribute_id = pdd.attribute_id AND pds.store_id=cs.store_id LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpe` ON cpe.entity_id = pdd.entity_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = pdd.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 97 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = pdd.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 97 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (pdd.store_id=0) AND (cs.store_id!=0) AND (pdd.attribute_id IN('82')) AND (IF(pds.value_id > 0, pds.value, pdd.value) IS NOT NULL) AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1)
so how to solve this for permanantly

Comment: Did you try it from the SSH command?

Comment: we used putty for reindex and then this above error shown .because we deleted some products before that.